# Terraform - override a single value in a map

Tags: terraform

I would like to know if it is possible to merge two map of maps without replacing the main map object.

My map object is defined as follows:

```
variable "apps" {
type = map(object({
 is_enabled    = bool
 cost_center   = string
}))
default = {}
}

locals {
  default_apps = {
    "api-1" = {
       is_enabled   = false
       cost_center  = "1234"
    },
    "api-2" = {
       is_enabled   = false
       cost_center  = "1235"
    },
  }
  apps = merge(
    local.default_apps,
    var.apps
  )
}
```

If define my tfars as follows, to override the value of api-1['s_enabled']

```
  apps = {
    "api-1" = {
      is_enabled   = true
    }
  }
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid value for input variable

The environment variable TF_VAR_apps does not contain a valid value for
variable "apps": element "api-1": attribute "cost_center" is required.
```

It works if I define my tfvars like so:

```
  apps = {
    "api-1" = {
      is_enabled   = true
      cost_center  = "1234"
    }
  }
```

My goal is to override a single value of one of the pre defined local variables under `default_apps` (e.x is_enabled) in tfvars.

Edit: requirements

Answer (score -1):

The error is not about your `merge` but about your `tfars`. The following variable is invalid in your case:

```
  apps = {
    "api-1" = {
      is_enabled   = true
    }
  }
```

as you explicitly defined it as:

```
type = map(object({
 is_enabled    = bool
 cost_center   = string
}))
```

Your `apps` is missing `cost_center` which is **required**. If you use [object](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html#structural-types) type, everything that you specify in type definition **must be provided**:

> Values that match the object type **must contain all of the specified keys**, and the value for each key must match its specified type.

Comment: Thank you Marcin for answering my question. I failed to mention that I am trying to override a variable that has been pre defined in locals. I agree if I were to add `api-3` in tfvars. I would need to define both cost_center and is_enabled

Comment: @AaronBandelli No problem, but your variable in `tfars` is called `apps` and you defined `variable "apps" ` to require `cost_center`. Rename it to something else if you don't want to use type definition from `variable "apps"`.